# Get to be called & is called

Tags: meaning-in-context

If this sentence was "is called", would the meaning change?

> Right in the middle of the chest a whole man was carved. He would make you laugh to look at him grinning away, though one couldn’t call his grinning laughing. He had hind legs like a goat’s, a little horn on his forehead, and a long beard. All his children called him “General Headquarters-Hindquarters-Gives-Orders-Front-and-Rear-Sergeant-Billygoat-Legs.” It was a difficult name to pronounce and **not many people get to be called by it,** but he must have been very important or why should anyone have taken trouble to carve him at all?

Comment: _Is called_ would not make sense here. You could say 'Not many people _are called_ by it'. _Get to_ is the second definition [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-to)

Comment: get to be [called, seen, described, etc. etc.]. It means: have the opportunity to be + a passive verb.

Comment: Where would you insert "is called"?? Do you mean, "are called"? And can you write out the complete sentence you're asking about? It will require other adjustments too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the meaning would change. ***Get to*** is an auxiliary verb which means:

> to have an opportunity to do something:
>
> - I never ***get to see*** her now that she’s moved to California. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-to))

It can be followed by a passive verb, as indicated in the comments.

Now, to have an opportunity to be called something is not the same with being called something, so ***not many people get to be called by it*** is not interchangeable with ***not many people are*** (not is) ***called by it***.